# Custom data directory during MySQL installation

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04

I would like to install MySQL within a Vagrant script, and have the databases in a  different directory (a shared folder between the Vagrant VM and the host).

I know that the data directory can be changed after installation:
[Change MySQL data dir](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137424/moving-mysql-datadir)

But is there a way of doing this fully automatically *during* installation in a shell script?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `datadir` can be configured in the mysql config file. On Ubuntu it is `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. If you want to change the value automatically in a shell script, you can do it right after installation, using [`sed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed):

```
sudo sed -i 's#datadir\s*=.*#datadir=/path/to/your/data#' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

You need to restart the mysql server after that:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, I get the error that "* /etc/init.d/mysql: ERROR: The partition with /home/vagrant/mysqldb is too full!"... which is not the case, however.